# RShiny: How to update textAreaInput with contents of a file via fileInput?

Tags: r, shiny

I am building a Shiny app that will use either 1) default content supplied in a text area field to form a query that will be executed by the app or 2) allow the user to upload a query from a text from a file, and then use that uploaded content (now in the textArea) as the query to execute. All the pieces are working except that I am unable to load the text file into the textAreaInput field. I have tried working with updateTextAreaInput. Few examples exist and I have been unsuccessful.

Here is some example code that successfully allows the user  to select a text file. After selection, the contents of the text file are displayed in the "Debug" section of the app. How can I get this content into the textAreaInput (or other editable text field like textArea) using updateTextAreaInput or other means?  Note I am using output$text instead of output$query for testing purposes...

Suggestions greatly appreciated, working code example even more so!

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Load Text File into textAreaInput"),
    wellPanel(
        column(12, fileInput('fileRQ',   'Load Text File')),
        fluidRow(
            textAreaInput(inputId="query", "Text Content",rows=12, width='90%', 
         "# Default/example text. To be replaced by content of a file.")
        )
    ),
    fluidRow(
       tags$hr(),
       tags$h3("Debug"),
       verbatimTextOutput("text")    
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    fileText <- eventReactive(input$fileRQ, {
        filePath <- input$fileRQ$datapath
        fileText <- paste(readLines(filePath), collapse = "\n")
        fileText
    })
    output$text <- fileText
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were so close. Just update the textAreaInput when a file was uploaded :) Note if you don't need the text otherwise, you can just use `oberveEvent` instead of `eventReactive`.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Load Text File into textAreaInput"),
  wellPanel(
    column(12, fileInput('fileRQ',   'Load Text File')),
    fluidRow(
      textAreaInput(inputId="query", "Text Content",rows=12, width='90%', 
                    "# Default/example text. To be replaced by content of a file.")
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    tags$hr(),
    tags$h3("Debug"),
    verbatimTextOutput("text")    
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # fileText() contains the recent file text
  fileText <- eventReactive(input$fileRQ, {
    filePath <- input$fileRQ$datapath
    fileText <- paste(readLines(filePath), collapse = "\n")

    # update text area with file content
    updateTextAreaInput(session, "query", value = fileText)

    # return the text to be displayed in text Outputs
    return(fileText)
  })

  output$text <- renderPrint({ fileText() })    
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome!  That works like a charm. The text will be passed as a query string so I will test that next within the (non-stripped down) app and go from there. Thanks so much. I can build a lot of different stuff on top of this now.